# Сомнение в правильности

Tags: грамотная-речь

Задался таким вопросом, мучает он меня))) Может ли тариф быть дешёвым или дорогим? Слух режет от этого. Это как цена дешёвая))) Просветите, пожалуйста, погуглил в яндексе, ничего не нашёл. Спасибо.

Comment: Зачем в тексте заборы?

Comment: @shampar Чтобы передать эмоции.

Comment: Вы на сайте с традиционным отношением к знакам и символам. И к размерности букв тоже.

Comment: А вы о каком тарифе говорите? Если о телефонном, то не вижу в этом ничего плохого.

Answer (score 1):

Тариф сам по себе не может быть дешёвым или дорогим. Имеется в виду размер стоимости, цена.  Это скорее метонимия. Однако в разговорной речи так сказать можно. Вот определение из **Большого толкового словаря.
ТАРИФ, -а; м. [франц. tarif] 1. Официально установленный размер или система размеров стоимости, оплаты, обложения чего-л. Железнодорожный т. Таможенный т. Тарифы налогов. Тарифы связи. Тарифы оплаты труда. Составить тарифы. Произвести оплату в соответствии с тарифом. 2. Таблица, свод ставок обложения, оплаты чего-л. и т.п. Сверить сумму с тарифом. <Тарифный, -ая, -ое. Т-ая система оплаты труда. Т-ая ставка. Т-ая сетка. Т-ая политика. Т-ое соглашение.**

Answer (score 0):

Если речь идёт о тарифе на телефон или интернет, то ты ведь именно его покупаешь. Т. е. цена не может быть дешёвой потому что ты покупаешь не цену, а товар. А в случае с тарифом ты покупаешь именно тариф.

Comment: Покупается скорее тарифный план, а не тариф. В свою очередь, тарифный план включает в себя набор различных тарифов на различные услуги, входящие в тарифный план (звонки, Интернет, SMS и т.д.)

Comment: @IvanOlshansky, а тарифный план нельзя назвать просто тарифом?

Comment: В качестве сокращенной формы для "бытового" применения - думаю, можно. Но все-таки тариф обычно бывает высоким или низким, а тарифный план уже может быть дешевым или дорогим.